# How use a machine int for limited ops bit set in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to use a machine int to represent a set containing zero or more of the numbers 1..9. This is to feed a foolish obsession with just how fast a sudoku solving algorithm I can build with Haskell, but all in a broader desire to extend my Haskell education. I'm finding having a real problem to work on a great motivator above the book exercises I've been able to find. I have it down to a couple milliseconds for a "very hard" but solvable-without-guessing puzzle, but am hoping for a next generation performance measured in microseconds :)

I would need the following operations:

- **Initialize** a set to include all members, which would correspond to the decimal number 511, or 0b111111111. I'm thinking something like s1 = MyBitSet(511), but any way that gets it done without having to set each bit individually would be fine.
- **set subtraction** - like 0b111111111 - 0b10101 => 111101010. In bitwise operations I believe this would be s1 OR complement(s2).
- **members** - like s2 = {2,4,6,7,8,9}

I've been puzzling over the code I've been able to find on search, but partly because my Haskell skills are still developing and partly because this is a bit of a specialized optimization, I'm having trouble making progress.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Early optimization is the downfall of programmers.  Profile your code, find the hot spots, and I'm willing to bet that you'll find that it isn't your int representation that's slowing you down the most.

Comment: Do you know about [Data.Bits](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Bits.html)? "Set" subtraction and "set" membership can be written with bitwise operations.

Comment: Hmm, that looks interesting @user2407038, I'll take a look at that module, I think it might do the trick, thanks :) I had gotten stuck on Data.BitSet and missed that one :)

Comment: @bheklilr Yes, you're right of course, normally I wouldn't pursue this sort of thing without evidence it was a root cause. It's just that right now any direction that raises my interest is a good one, motivating new exploration :)  I'll be vigilant against falling into bad habits :)

Comment: @scanny Doing it purely as a learning exercise is completely different, in which case I encourage you to pursue this diligently!  I just warn against it because I was bitten by this just this past week at work, I thought using C would give me a big speed boost over Python, but for this particularly problem NumPy was already making it as fast as I could really get it.

Comment: If you want to measure such minuscule times, you will need to run many tests. Are you using [criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion)? If not, you should be. If you want to go all out, you should probably also examine the Core using `-ddump-simpl` to make sure the `Int`s are getting unboxed, and perhaps even grovel over the generated assembly or LLVM code.

Comment: @dfeuer I like it! I'm in the mood for some assembly groveling somehow, taking me back to my early days in C :) Thanks for the pointers (no pun intended:) I'm not sure where this performance obsession is coming from, and not sure that's really the promise of Haskell in the first place, but I'm learning a lot as I pursue it which is all I was really after. Following along with the book exercises was leaving me a bit cold :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestions of @user2407038 above, I worked out the following module that seems to do the job nicely, and gave me occasion to get a number of Haskell concepts straight in my head for the first time:

```
--
-- A simple, hopefully very fast Sudoku markup set implementation
--

module MarkupSet where

import Data.Bits ((.&.), complement, setBit, testBit)
import Data.Word (Word)
import Test.HUnit


type MarkupSet = Word


-- initialized MarkupSet value, 511 decimal, 0b111111111 binary
defaultMarkupSet :: MarkupSet
defaultMarkupSet = 511

-- an empty set is also handy in some cases
emptyMarkupSet :: MarkupSet
emptyMarkupSet = 0

-- construct a MarkupSet from an Int (Word) value, e.g. markupSet 42
markupSet :: Word -> MarkupSet
markupSet x = x

-- construct a MarkupSet from list of values, e.g. [1,3,5]
fromValues :: [Int] -> MarkupSet
fromValues = foldl (\acc n -> setBit acc (n-1)) emptyMarkupSet
-- based on comment from @dfeuer, updated from:
-- fromValues [] = markupSet 0
-- fromValues (n:ns) = setBit (fromValues ns) (n - 1)

-- a list of the integer members 1..9 in a MarkupSet, e.g. [1,3,5]
enumMembers :: MarkupSet -> [Int]
enumMembers s = [ i+1 | i <- [0..8], testBit s i]

-- set difference, aka complement set: members of s not in s'
-- e.g difference {1,3,5,8} {1,2,3} -> {5,8}
difference :: MarkupSet -> MarkupSet -> MarkupSet
difference s s' = s .&. (complement s')

-- 9-digit binary string representation, e.g. "001011010"
showBits :: MarkupSet -> String
showBits s = [ if testBit s i then '1' else '0' | i <- [8,7..0] ]


-- ===================================================================
-- Tests
-- ===================================================================

case_default_has_all_members = TestCase $ assertEqual
    "defaultMarkupSet should have all bits set"
    "111111111"
    (showBits defaultMarkupSet)

case_construct_from_int = TestCase $ assertEqual
    "can construct from Int literal"
    "000101010"
    (showBits $ markupSet 42)

case_construct_from_values = TestCase $ assertEqual
    "can construct from list of ints in range [1..9]"
    297
    (fromValues [1,4,6,9])

case_enum_int_members = TestCase $ assertEqual
    "can enumerate its integer members"
    [2,4,6]
    (enumMembers $ markupSet 42)

case_subtract_sets = TestCase $ assertEqual
    "can calculate set difference"
    [1,3,5,7,8,9]
    (enumMembers $ difference defaultMarkupSet (markupSet 42))


tests = 
    [ case_default_has_all_members
    , case_construct_from_int
    , case_construct_from_values
    , case_enum_int_members
    , case_subtract_sets
    ]


main = do
    runTestTT $ TestList tests
```

Comment: `fromValues` is a fold, and you should write it as one to take advantage of special optimization rules for folds. But you've written it as a *right* fold, when you surely want to structure it as a *left* fold. I don't think *any* of this will be significant for a Sudoku solver, but if you're trying to learn basic Haskell optimizations, give that a try.